# Chef Configuration setting

Tags: chef-recipe

I am trying to configure for copying  files  through chef.However,we have a requirement to push  configuration only  for couple of servers. Is there any parameter or setting for that ?

Elaborated a little more .....

Our standard deployment through Chef requires that the latest build be deployed to all servers.
However, individual developers also submit experimental builds that are deployed to 1-2 servers per developer only as opposed to the entire stack.
Our objectives are as follows:
1.  Be able to deploy experimental builds through Chef to a specified set of servers. 
2.  Prevent experimental builds from being deployed to the servers that already host experimental builds – perhaps have the Chef server mark those servers as unavailable somehow(?)
3.  Be able to deploy full builds to either all servers or only those servers that are not used for experimental builds at the moment.

I’m sure it’s a fairly common scenario and would  like to know if there is an elegant/effective/dynamic  way to keep Chef server informed of where each build/experiment should be  deployed to.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a cloud provider, the answer is to use Packer to create an image for each build, and then deploy images as needed.  If you use bare metal, then you can easily use either normal attributes or roles to setup the versions.  I'd suggest attributes.

1. Set `node['myapp']['test_version']` = 'some version' on the nodes to be updated
2. In your recipe, check the value of that attribute.  If set, then install that version, otherwise install your master version.

To remove a node from the experiment, you can just reset that attribute to nil on the node.  The next chef run will result in that node going back to the master version.

If you want a way to install the master version on ALL nodes, including ones that are in experiments, you can either write a second recipe that ignores the setting, or you can add an override attribute like `node['myapp']['force_master']` or such.  You could then set that on the environment to override the experiments.  But you'd need to remember to reset it at a later time.